# multer create folder if not exist

Tags: node.js, multer

I saw in documentation of multer, that if folder doesn't exist, the multer will not create folder.  How can i create a folder if not exist?

```
import multer from 'multer'
import crypto from 'crypto'
import { extname, resolve } from 'path'
import slug from 'slug'

export default {
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'uploads', 'gallery'),
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const { id, description } = req.body

      crypto.randomBytes(8, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return cb(err)

        return cb(null, id + '/' + res.toString('hex') + '/' + slug(description, { lower: true }) + extname(file.originalname))
        // return cb(null, res.toString('hex') + extname(file.originalname))
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

i had change to:

```
import multer from 'multer'
import crypto from 'crypto'
import { extname } from 'path'
import slug from 'slug'
import fs from 'fs'

export default {
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      const { id } = req.body
      const path = `./uploads/gallery/${id}`
      fs.mkdirSync(path, { recursive: true })
      return cb(null, path)
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const { description } = req.body

      crypto.randomBytes(3, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return cb(err)

        return cb(null, slug(description, { lower: true }) + '_' + res.toString('hex') + extname(file.originalname))
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: You should use `mkdirSync` only if the directoyy doesn't exists (you could `existsSync` function wich returns a boolean).

Comment: exist is deprecated method, i can do this, with code above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*I have done it in this way, and  it works fine for me. so you can try. hopefully it will work for you. good luck*

#########controller##########

```
// image Upload
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require("fs");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {

        balayAudPath = 'media/content/agriInput/balay/audio'

        fs.mkdirSync(balayAudPath, { recursive: true })
        cb(null, balayAudPath)
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({
        storage: storage
    }).fields([
        { name: 'contentAudio', maxCount: 1 }
    ])
    //.single('imageFile');
    // .array('images', 3)  //| for upload multiple files

module.exports = {
    upload
}
```

###### router

```
xxxRouterWeb.post('/addXXXAudio', auth,
        xxxController.upload, xxxController.addBalayAudio)
```